# Array to json with json_encode and back to text

Tags: php, json

I retrieve data from a mysql database. I want to make this data available as json:

```
<?php
    $data = array();

    foreach($this->dataFromDb as $value){
        $data[] = $value;
    }

    $json = json_encode($data);

    echo $json;
?>
```

Unfortunately this produces `null` values in the json because e.g. `$value['title']` may contain non utf-8 chars like €. To solve this I change this line.

```
$data[] = array_map(utf8_encode, $value);
```

But now I have strings like `\u00` or `\u0080` in the json output. How would I get my normal text like it is stored in db from the json? When I try

```
print_r(json_decode($json));
```

I again get strange chars like `fÃ¼r 599,95Â€`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) the data:

```
<?php

    $data = array();
    $arr[] = 'a';
    $arr[] = "\x80";

    print_r($arr);

    $data[] = array_map(utf8_encode, $arr);

    $json = json_encode($data);

    $decoded_json =  json_decode($json);

    print_r($decoded_json);

    $decoded_data[] = array_map(utf8_decode, $decoded_json[0] );
    print_r($decoded_data);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iconv to convert between charsets.

```
iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use utf-8 charset per connection to the database.